# Returning value of array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I'm trying to return the value of a matched array key from an sqlite database, where once a message contains a word it matches (which I have working), but then I'd like to return the value (in this case length) of the matched key. Example.

Array: `[ 'hello', 5000, 'world', 2000 ]`

My code for returning a chat message of 'true' if the message sent contains a word in the above array

```
var amarray = [];
con.all(
  "SELECT phrase, length FROM automod_data WHERE type = 'mute'",
  (err, rows) => {
    rows.forEach(function(row) {
      amarray.push(row.phrase, row.length);
    });
    console.log(amarray);

    if (amarray.some(v => message.content.includes(v))) {
      message.reply("true");

      logembed = new discord.RichEmbed().setFooter(`ID: amarray[1]`);

      client.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "logs").send(logembed);
    }
    return amarray;
  }
);
```

So the above returns 'true' when 'hello' is spoken. I'd also like to return the value '5000'

Comment: My goal is so that if a user says 'hello', then it replies with 'true' and the value of hello as defined in the array, so '5000' however I can't manage to get the word it triggered for to pass through, so I can't look it up in the array

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pushing each value as a separate array element, push the object as a whole.

```
rows.forEach(function(row) {
  amarray.push(row);
});
```

Then you can search for the element that matches `v`.

```
var match = amarray.find(v => message.content.includes(v.phrase));
if (match) {
    console.log("true", matching.length);
}
```